# Terraform loop and data source from other loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a problem I am creating targret groups in Terraform for AWS and assigning ALB listeners and certificates to them. Creating multiple target groups is not working for me. Problem, I use the basic for_each construct. However, for the ALB listener module I need to define the target group and certificate created for the tg. I thought to load the certificates with another count for the data source (the certificates are created from another module).

```
# Certificate Data
data "aws_acm_certificate" "generic_certificate" {
  count  = length(var.domain_name)
  domain = var.domain_name[count.index]
}
```

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "alb_generic_https_listener" {
 for_each          = { for target in var.target_groups : target.name => target }
 load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.generic_alb.arn
 port              = var.https_listener_port
 protocol          = var.https_listener_protocol
 ssl_policy        = var.https_policy
 certificate_arn   = data.aws_acm_certificate.generic_certificate[count.index].arn

 default_action {
   type             = var.https_default_action_type
   target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.generic_alb_tg[each.key].arn
 }
}

#ALB Target Group
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "generic_alb_tg" {
 for_each    = { for target in var.target_groups : target.name => target }
 name        = "${each.value.name}-${var.environment}"
 port        = each.value.port
 protocol    = each.value.protocol
 target_type = each.value.target_type
 vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.vpc.id
 
 tags = {
   Environment = var.environment
   Region      = var.region
   Type        = each.value.resource_type
 }
}

variable "domain_name" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "Domain name for SSL Certificate"
}

variable "target_groups" {
  type = list(object({
    name          = string
    port          = string
    protocol      = string
    target_type   = string
    resource_type = string
  }))
}
```

Unfortunately I'm struggling with the fact that I can't use two cycles for one resource. Can you think of any way around the problem?

The result is that I imagine I will be able to assign a target group and certificate to the listener.

Comment: What type of variable is `domain_name`? A list? Would you also mind adding the `target_groups` variable to the question?

Comment: I have added a description of the variables, hopefully it will help to better understand my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a more complete map with all you info in a locals. After, refer to the local in your loop.

Create a map instant of a list and then, use a for_each.
You will then be able to use :

```
data.aws_acm_certificate.generic_certificate[keyOfYourMap].arn
```

Instead of the index.